Auto Connect to Primary Database from Spring Boot
I have a FDNS(mydbfdns.example.com) defined which has two Database servers A and B under it(Primary and StandBy) and resolves to Primary Database (A) and same is been used in the Spring Boot application properties file under spring.jdbc.url.
However when I update the FDNS to repoint to Server B which acts as Primary during failover exercises, the application is still getting the connection from DB Server A instead of Server B even though I use the FDNS. I had to restart the application to get it connected to Server B.
I tried using testOnBorrow and validationQuery but they didn't work, can someone shed light on how to achieve this without restarting application.

You can't switch your DBs using your DNS settings without putting your application in maintenance mode, wait all user sessions finished, and then flush the connection pool. All this means you have designed your application to have a maintenance mode, have an admin page or a tool where you can monitor the sessions and a way to trigger a flush of the pool...
